# Trello voting - how?

Tags: trello

I've just seen the option to set voting permissions in Trello.

What can you vote on (boards, cards, comments) and how do you vote (I can't see any up/down arrows)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the last version, it is placed under Power-Ups in the menu

[image: Powerups]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the permissions form; I think that would be much more helpful.

Comment: It's pretty basic just adds a Checkbox under the "Watch" under actions on a card.

Answer (score 5):

There's a vote button (up votes only).

Open the card (detail view), select the small "more" link beneath the card options on the right hand side (next to the card number), the first option is the vote button.

**UPDATE:**

Since the end of 2013, voting permissions are under Power-Ups (as per the accepted answer).
Actual voting is still on the card's detail view.

Comment: So you ask a question and aswer it within the hour. You actually searched this before asking it?

Comment: @i.am.michiel I've searched this before asking, and found this answer, and it was useful to me.

Comment: @i.am.michiel — [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Think of it as knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 4):

At Voting plugin, click on the gear icon, you can config voting permission.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Vote button no longer appears by default, even when you click the "More..." button on a card.

You need to set the Board permissions to have Voting Enabled. On the Sidebar, click Menu -> Settings -> Voting Permissions.

[image]

You can now access voting by simply opening the card, the vote button is now just above the archive button:

[image]

Comment: This seems to have moved again. I just followed these instructions and there was no 'voting permissions' button in Menu->Settings. Instead, I could enable voting by going to Menu->Power Ups->Voting

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, the way to add voting to a board is to open the board's menu, where you'll see three slots for Power-Ups.

[image: Trello Menu pane with three "Power-Ups" slots.]

Clicking on one of the slots where it says "Add Power-Up..." will take you to the Power-Ups listing, where you can search for the power-up you want. It conveniently starts searching as you're typing, so you don't need to fill in the full name before it will appear:

[image: Searching for "vot" will make the Voting powerup appear quickly in the search menu]

Click the "Add" button to choose this Power-Up for one of the slots on your board.

You can also configure *who* can vote by using the cog that appears in the upper right corner after you add the Power-Up. You can choose to allow voting by the Members, Members and Observers, Team Members, or make it Public for everyone who visits your board.

[image: Options for who can vote on the Board]

You can only vote on cards.

To cast a vote, there are a few options.

- If you're looking at the board, you can vote by hovering your cursor over the card and tapping the "v" key on your keyboard (and remove the vote by pressing "v" again.
- If you have the card open, you can use the "Vote" button in the lower right corner.
  [image: "Vote" button on a Trello card]
- In their mobile app, they added the ability to vote mid-2017 and the process is similar to the previous. There's a "Vote" button on the card if you expand it.

You can also see how many votes there are and who voted.

From the board, it will show the number of votes:

[image: Trello Board with one card that has been upvoted]

And from the card view, you can see the count of votes at the top of the card and, by clicking on the button, it will show the list of who voted:

[image: Vote counter with a single vote on a Trello Card]